# Xcode: How to reveal programmatically png image

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, gps

I have to make a speedometer.
I have a speed bar (png file) that I want to reval when the gps speed change.

[image: speed bar]

Example ... max speed set to 100 (km/h).
When I'm at 50 km/h the bar is visible at 50%.
Whem I'm at 40 km/h the app show me 40% of the bar.

I would you like to put an image above the speed bar image, and hide the first image dependently the gps speed.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for Emily? Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then revise your question. If you don't know where to start at all, I suggest using tutorials to get you started.

Comment: Hi, i m loking for help to make a graphic speedometer, for my iphone app. I finished the gps code and now i want to integrate the graphical part. i m using xcode 7.0

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple hack you can use to achieve this effect. You can encompass the `ImageView` inside another `UIView`. Give `Autolayout Constraints` for the `ImageView`'s Leading, Top and Bottom Space. Don't add a trailing space constraint. Now when you change the `UIView`s width, you can see the image being revealed as per your input.

Here's the structure :

[image]

and the autolayout constraints :

1)SpeedoHolder:
[image]

2)CoverView:
[image]

3)ImageView:
[image]

Now Connect up the required outlets in `viewController.h`. I'm using a slider for demonstration:

```
//Trailing space constraint of CoverView
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *trailingSpaceConstraint;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *slider;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *speedoHolder;

- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(id)sender;
```

And Now the implementation:

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(id)sender {
  CGFloat newVal = self.slider.value;

  self.trailingSpaceConstraint.constant = self.speedoHolder.frame.size.width * (1-newVal);

  [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
  [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

PS: dont forget to enable `Clips Subviews` for `CoverView` in `Attributes Inspector`.

**Update:** you can fine tune the hiding by modifying the value of `trailingSpaceConstraint.constant`. i.e. if you have a max speed and current(GPS) speed, do this:

```
self.trailingSpaceConstraint.constant = self.speedoHolder.frame.size.width * (gpsSpeed / maxSpeed);
```

Comment: Thank ShahiM, this is what i want to do... i m sorry for my english. In this WE i ll try this code. Where i can set the max speed of my car ? And i ll try to link the gps speed to the UIViews width s. it s correct?